# Conditional module injection in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I'm working on an Ionic project and trying to use Angular-UI's angular-google-maps.

However, since the regular, blocking way of loading the Maps JS API occasionally takes too long
the app times out.

I'm trying to make angular-google-maps 'load' only when Google Maps' script finishes loading async, by using the defer attribute and loading the script asynchronously.

The problem is that the module is initialised before 'google' is available and it breaks.
I'm looking for a way to delay the initialization of this module until it is possible to use.

Is there a way of having a 'proxy' or 'alias' module that injects the needed module when needed?

Or is there another way to control dependancy injection conditionally?

Thanks!

Comment: If it does not actually _use_ anything in the `document.google.maps` namespace then you can _mock_ it (initialize it to an empty object or something before it's actually loaded).

Comment: That just might work, I'll test that now. If it is referencing properties of the namespace, will these references persist when the API finishes loading?

Comment: Probably, _use_ includes referencing too unfortunately. That's because when the remote JS finishes loading it overwrites `document.google.maps`. The old value will still exist if it's referenced by other code.